# How to use Google Tasks on the web standalone?

Tags: javascript, google-tasks, userscripts

I'd like to use Google Tasks without having to open Gmail or Google Calendar or Google Docs. How can I do that?

It used to be possible with mail.google.com/tasks/canvas

Comment: assistant.google.com/tasks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use one of the following 3 approaches to open Google Tasks in a single step:

1. **https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://calendar.google.com**

   - If you have multiple Google accounts logged in at the same time, you can specify a secondary account by appending the `authuser` parameter. If the specified user isn't logged in to your session, it will redirect to the default user.
     Replace `[google-account]` with the actual target account's address:

     ```
     &authuser=[google-account]
     ```
   - For example, if you have a secondary logged in account `joeblo@gmail.com` the full URL will be:

     ```
     https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://calendar.google.com&authuser=joeblo@gmail.com
     ```
2. **https://assistant.google.com/tasks**

   - This approach also supports the `authuser` parameter. Use the same instructions as in #1 above, however, since this is the first and only parameter, use the question mark `?`, not the ampersand `&`:

     ```
     ?authuser=[google-account]

     https://assistant.google.com/tasks?authuser=joeblo@gmail.com
     ```
3. **https://calendar.google.com/tasks** 
   or 
   **https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/tasks**

   - Technically, this opens Google Calendar, which may disqualify it. Still, it accesses Tasks in a single step using a single URL and is a good option if the additional clicks are what you seek to avoid.
   - Use of the `authuser` parameter require the longer URL. As the first and only parameter, use the question mark `?`, not the ampersand `&`:

     ```
     ?authuser=[google-account]

     https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/tasks?authuser=joeblo@gmail.com
     ```

Answer (score 1):

I used simplegamer solution with [tasks.google.com/embed](https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://calendar.google.com&fullWidth=1) link but for javascript I prefer greasemonkey, so you save 1 click every time.

This is the script I use in greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     google tasks
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
// @match https://tasks.google.com/embed/list/~default?fullWidth=1
// @match https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://calendar.google.com&fullWidth=1
javascript:document.querySelector('body').style.display=null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also an old Google Tasks Canvas user, and I built a complete replacement web app for it (with upgrades) called GTaskD that you can use for free: https://tasks.gtaskd.com/

Warning: 2019-08-30 is the date that [Google will get rid of multiple levels of subtasks](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/upcoming-change-google-tasks-api) in the API itself (as opposed to just their interfaces), so third party apps won't be able to support them directly anymore. I'm building my own API/backend that will sync with theirs, but I can't make that part free, so there will be a small fee.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with stylus, or another user stylesheet manager:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("https://tasks.google.com/embed/") {
body[style] {
  display: initial !important;
}
}
```